# EnumChildWindows never calls its callback

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to manipulate a specific Internet Explorer 11 window. Using WinSpy++ I find that

1. The top level window's class is an IEFrame with the title of the document as the text (as returned by GetWindowText)
2. The actual web view class is called "Internet Explorer_Server" and is a child of the former.

I wrote a simple test case for finding the web view of IE11 opened on "https://encrypted.google.com/" in three different ways:

```
HWND FindIE_A()
{
    // Use FindWindow, works!
    HWND hWndTop = ::FindWindowA( NULL, "Google - Internet Explorer" );
    // Find the web view window, the callback (FindIEServer) is NEVER called!
    HWND hWnd = NULL;
    ::EnumChildWindows( hWndTop, &FindIEServer, (LPARAM)&hWnd );
    return hWnd;
}
HWND FindIE_B()
{
    // Use EnumChildWindows with NULL as parent, works!
    HWND hWndTop = NULL;
    ::EnumChildWindows( NULL, &FindIEMain, (LPARAM)&hWndTop );
    // Find the web view window, the callback (FindIEServer) is NEVER called!
    HWND hWnd = NULL;
    ::EnumChildWindows( hWndTop, &FindIEServer, (LPARAM)&hWnd );
    return hWnd;
}
HWND FindIE_C()
{
    // Simple EnumWindows, works!
    HWND hWndTop = NULL;
    ::EnumWindows( &FindIEMain, (LPARAM)&hWndTop );
    // Find the web view window, the callback (FindIEServer) is NEVER called!
    HWND hWnd = NULL;
    ::EnumChildWindows( hWndTop, &FindIEServer, (LPARAM)&hWnd );
    return hWnd;
}
```

The callbacks that are very simple; get a property from the window and compare against a hard-coded value:

```
BOOL CALLBACK FindIEServer( HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
    char className[64];
    ::GetClassNameA( hWnd, className, sizeof(className) );
    if ( !strcmp( className, "Internet Explorer_Server" ) )
    {
        *(HWND*)lParam = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL CALLBACK FindIEMain( HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
    char text[128];
    ::GetWindowTextA( hWnd, text, sizeof(text) );
    if ( !strcmp( text, "Google - Internet Explorer" ) )
    {
        *(HWND*)lParam = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

EnumChildWindows failed (by not calling the callback AT ALL!) every time when provided with a parent window. Why?

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is with this, but you're probably better off using IE automation via COM. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167658 for an example

Comment: Maybe Internet Explorer doesn't want you diddling it's children.

Comment: Are you trying to get controls in a web page, such as those in a web form? If so, you should know that [those are not real controls with real window handles, but rather IE simulating real controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/11/371042.aspx).

Comment: @wakjah I'm trying to embed a browser inside a directx9 game. I'm able to capture the window pixels and stream into a texture and draw it. I'm currently looking to be able to control that from inside the game. Thanks for that link, seems very interesting, will check it out!

Comment: The `Internet Explorer_Server` window is not an **immediate** child of `IEFrame`, it is nested several layers deep. Even if you got `EnumChildWindows()` working, it would not find `Internet Explorer_Server` unless you call it numerous times.  In this situation, you should use `FindWindowEx()` instead of `EnumChildWindows()`.

Comment: You didn't check return values for errors. You should do some debugging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan These functions don't SetLastError, the either return the correct value or 'NULL'. (I checked, I also stepped through the disassembly). I also have a work-around (will post answer in a bit)

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed, and EnumChildWindow explicitly states in the MSDN that it will return children of children "If a child window has created child windows of its own, EnumChildWindows enumerates those windows as well."

Comment: You need to check the return values for error. You don't. The documentation is clear. hWndTop could be NULL. Omitting error checking is the most basic mistake.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah I see what you mean, I am checking everything thoroughly in my actual code, this was a test case I wrote just to post here. It appears that there are multiple windows with the title and I'm getting the first one which happens to not have any children (thus does not call my callback). Adding a title check + classname check for IEFrame fixes it.

Comment: It's a waste of our time if you don't post the real code.

Comment: It won't let me post an answer yet, I will when it'll let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when I look for the window title, I was assuming there was only one window with that title. However Internet Explorer does some shenanigans and creates multiple windows with the same title however only one of them has the class IEFrame.

It just so happens that the first window found was the wrong one, it didn't have any children (and thus EnumChildWindows doesn't have anything to iterate over). Just adding an extra check for title + class works.

However as @wakjah suggested, it is better integrate IE (or any other browser) directly into your code. With google I found lots of documentation on how to do this with both IE and Chrome.