# How to know which className to search for with EnumChildWindows()?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am looking for the classNames of the form fields in a parent window.

[Parent Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfr4W.jpg)

I find the parent window with: `handle = FindWindowA(NULL, "Riot Client");`

I enumerate through the parents child windows with: `EnumChildWindows(handle, &findChild, (LPARAM)&child);`

`findChild()` written as:

```
BOOL CALLBACK findChild(HWND child, LPARAM lParam) {
    char className[64];
    ::GetClassNameA(child, className, sizeof(className));
    std::cout << className;
    std::cout << "\n";      
    if (!strcmp(className, "Riot Client")) {
        *(HWND*)lParam = child;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I have tried to find the child window with `std::cout << className;` in the callback.
classNames provided from the callback are:

```
RCLIENT
CefBrowserWindow
Chrome_WidgetWin_0
Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND
```

Further using `FindWindowA()` with these class names doesn't provide anything useful.

[Research for EnumChildWindows().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943872/enumchildwindows-never-calls-its-callback)
I notice here the className in the callback is specifically for the child window. This is what I'm trying to find. Currently I'm just searching for the parent windows className.

[EnumChildWindows() documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows)

---

UPDATE

[I used inspect to find some more information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAAWM.png)

It seems like from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175036/14199954), communicating with these fields are impossible.

Comment: That is a "Nw.JS" type application. Basically, the UI is a webpage/HTML. There are no Win32 child windows in there. Maybe you could inject Selenium in there.

Comment: You can prove me wrong by using a program like Spy++ to view window hierarchy of that specific window.

Comment: @Andy I just tried Spy++.
It didn't return all the children: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/538b2a0a-80f2-4752-858c-837b9297a962/spy-is-not-returning-all-child-windows?forum=vcgeneral

Instead it suggests to use inspector instead. Which I've done and found some better results.

Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure that application is either using NW.JS framework, or Electron framework. Regardless, you may be able to inject Selenium in to it and automate it that way. You'll have to google it.

Comment: If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). Use [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to verify whether the target application implements the required interfaces. If it doesn't you'll have to investigate, whether the application offers a custom automation protocol. If neither of these are available, there's nothing you can do.